# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "myapp.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Read through all the previous questions and no solutions have helped me.

There are no temp files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

There is only one `.conf` file and one server block (not including `CertBot`).

I've unlinked `default` from `sites-enabled` so I only have my site enabled.

I'm only including my site in the include statements in the conf file.

I have a feeling it has to do with the `CertBot` server block but am not sure how to resolve it.

Grateful for feedback.

## `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
    server_tokens off;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @python_django;
    }
    location @python_django {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Ce$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by $
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

## `nginx.conf` file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript tex$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp;
}
```

Comment: The file `myapp` contains two `server` blocks, both listening on port 80 and both with a `server_name` containing `myapp.com`.

Comment: What can I do as the second server block was configured by CertBot?

Comment: How do you want your server to respond to `http` requests to `myapp.com`?

Comment: On LetsEncrypt I set it up so that they are forwarded to https

Comment: In that case, the `listen 80;` in the first `server` block should be deleted.